# White region in ContourPlot

Tags: plotting

The following code

```
ContourPlot[Min[(-7 + 100 t - x) (5 + 100 t - x), (400 t^2 + 40 t (-5 + x) + (-5 + x) (7 + x))], {t, 0, .05}, {x, -1, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

gives an ugly picture:

[image]

Why does it not plot the entire data?

Checking with excel gives the following

[image]

Pardon me if this is already addressed. I looked but did not find any relevant answer other than `PlotRange->All`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ContourPlot[Min[(-7 + 100 t - x) (5 + 100 t - x), (400 t^2 + 40 t (-5 + x) + (-5 + x) (7 + x))], 
   {t, 0, .05}, {x, -1, 5}, PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None]
```

`Exclusions->None` fixes the issue in both version 9 and 10:
[image]

Without the `Exclusions->None` option, I reproduce the issue in both versions  (Windows 8 - 64bit):

[image]

Comment: In _my_ v9 (win) it doesn't need `Exclusions->`. Shows OK by default

Comment: @belisarius, i am using v9.0.1.0 (Windows 8 -64bit).

Comment: @belisarius For me too. Win7.

Comment: Win 32 v9.0.1 here

Comment: Thank you folks. I was using Win8.1 v10.